# Which colors should I use for a game result graph?

Tags: android, design, mobile-application, color-scheme, games

I'm designing a game app for Android. We have three states for the game result with the following colors.

1. Win - Green
2. Tie - Yellow
3. Lose - Red

What do you think about this color combination? Is this the right choice for this state? Or do you know a useful article for this situation?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your colours are pretty irrelevant because you are using textual callout labels to re-enforce the meaning, e.g. 550 Winning, 228 Lose, 204 Tie.

Because of this you can now offer a new feature to the user - personalize the colours.

Of course, if you are using text to unambiguously communicate the results, you have to question the use of a circular graphic, where exactness will be much more difficult to discern. Here I am assuming your players really want to know how many times they won, tied or lost. You need to be very careful about the use of graphics to communicate meaning. A bar graph might be a better choice.

Stephen Few's book Information Dashboard Design has some great examples.

Answer (score 0):

**Color** manipulation in design is very important. Sometimes this is due to personal preference, and other times due to professional background. Color knowledge is a science in itself. Studying how colors affect different people, either individually or as a group, is something some people build their careers on.

Apart from me your color combination is okay ! and I attach some link where you get a lot of color combination.

[COLORHUNT](http://colorhunt.co/)

[Material UI](http://www.materialui.co/colors)

[Adobe Kuler](https://color.adobe.com/)
[image]